# Excel displays html code

Tags: php, html, excel

I want create excel sheet from html code my code is below.

```
 <?php

include_once("database/connect.php");

$db->mquery('a_menus','*');
$types=$db->fetchdata();

$menus=array();
$menus=$types->menu_name;

$file = "test.csv";
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");

$fh = fopen('php://output', 'w');
foreach($menus as $data){ fputcsv($fh, $data); }
fclose($fh);

?>
```

Pls ,Can u tell me what's error.

Comment: You need to start by recognising that csv !== excel (BIFF or OfficeOpenXML) !== html - if you send CSV headers, then the file will be treated as a CSV file by your browser, which it isn't because it's html markup rather than a csv, and neither a csv nor html markup is an Excel file in either of the two standard Excel formats (BIFF or OfficeOpenXML)... and just naming a file with a .xls extension doesn't automagically make it an Excel file

Comment: pls explain clearly.

Comment: csv (comma seperated values) is a text file format. An office application like MSExcel or Libreoffice treats each comma-separated value as a cell and displays in a tabular form.
MSExcel files are not mere text files. It is a binary file format.[link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc313154(v=office.14).aspx). Renaming a text file will not change its file format.
Try to open a csv file and an Excel file in a text editor. You will see the difference !!!.

Answer (score 1):

I can open the file that your code produces in MS Excel 2013, however it displays a warning:

> The file format and extension of "test.xls" don't match. The file
>   could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open
>   it.

There are some minors problems with your code, such as incorrect charset name (should be `ISO-8859-1`) and confusing `Content-type` header. Most likely your problem is caused by using older version of Excel not being able to recognize HTML format.

To produce a correct CSV file that will be opened by all MS Excel versions (and its alternatives), and avoid incorrect format warning, use the code below.

```
<?php

$file = "test.csv";

$results = array(
   array('cell 1', 'cell 2')
);

header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");

$fh = fopen('php://output', 'w');
foreach($results as $data){ fputcsv($fh, $data); }
fclose($fh);

?>
```

As stated by commenters, just naming a file with `.xls` extension will not make an Excel file.

Answer (score -1):

The other answers are not true.

Excel can read files with .xls extension with HTML inside and your code is working for me.

I think the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Excel ___can___ read files with .xls extension with HTML inside; but __some (more recent) versions__ of MS EXcel  ___will___ issue the warning that the OP is getting.... just because it works without notice on the version of MS Excel that you're running, doesn't mean that it's the same for everyone, and writing html in a .xls file is still not correct, especially when using a mime type of csv

Comment: You are right for the content type but not for the xls content. A CSV file is not text file with html inside too. And the Op is telling us that is not working not that he has a warning opening it.

Comment: I am correct on both counts: `csv !== excel (BIFF or OfficeOpenXML) !== html`